# iOS: delegate from child to parent view

Tags: ios, delegates

Here is what I wish to do:

There is a parent `ViewController`. On parent's load, `ChildVC` is called which contains a `UITableView`.

Now on childView's table's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I wish to pass the selected cell content to parentView. And from parentView I wish to load a second viewController.

How do I do this by delegate?

**Edited:**

`Child :`

```
    @class ViewController;
@protocol CustomViewControllerDelegate;
@interface CustomViewController : UITableViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
     id<CustomViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<CustomViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol CustomViewControllerDelegate

-(void)didSelectRow:(NSString *)str;

@end
```

`parent`

```
    @class CustomViewController;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CustomViewControllerDelegate> // i get the error here
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ChildVC declare a protocol:

```
@protocol ChildVCDelegate
- (void)didSelectCell:(SomeContent *)content;
@end
```

Also add the delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ChildVCDelegate> delegate;
```

In the implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, add:

```
if (_delegate) {
    [_delegate didSelectCell:someContent];
}
```

In the parent view controller implement `didSelectCell` and when it creates/shows the ChildVC, set it as the delegate.

I'm not sure what kind of content you want to pass to the parent, so I represented it as SomeContent, but it can be whatever you want to pass.

Comment: When you use `strong` for delegate you create retain cycle: ChildVC retains ParentVC by delegate, ParentVC retains ChildVC by containing it. Need use `weak` to destroy retain cycle.

Comment: @MatíasR - Thanks but in parentVC I am getting compile time error- Caanot find protocol declaration `CustomViewControllerDelegate`. I have declared it in childVC. Where am I getting wrong? Please see my edited question to see my code.

Comment: Are you #importing CustomViewController.h in the parent view controller? You shouldn't need to declare @class CustomViewController in the parent

Comment: Got my error- I was declaring parentVC in childVC. When I commented the import, the code worked. I wonder why but. And yes you are right there's no need of @class. I commented that too. Thanks mate